# DC-DC converter in "parallel"

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, buck

I'm designing a system that needs two converters. The ***Vin*** input voltage is approximately 14.5V. I need to lower the ***Vin*** voltage to 12V and also to 5V. I chose two *LM2576-5 (5V)* and *LM2596-12 (12V)* converters, the two converters require a ***100uF Cin*** capacitor. I put a ***100uF Cin*** capacitor for each converter. Looking at the schematic below, as the Vin voltage goes to the two converters, the capacitors ***C6*** and ***C8*** in this scheme seem to be in parallel, resulting in a total capacitance of 200uF. I wonder, can this affect the functionality of the converters? The correct would be to put only one capacitor for the two converters? What can I be doing wrong by putting the capacitors in this way?
[image]

Comment: It depends on rated current and Vin min

Comment: Assuming all else is specified well, this arrangement should be fine. The input capacitors are (generally) not part of the feedback or stabilization part of the converters and are used for providing locally available charge to the converter circuit. Just be sure to put each input cap near its converter.

Comment: As an aside, your C6 voltage value is low

Comment: Assuming al the other components are what they should be, I give this a 99% chance that it will **just work**. Place both Caps near their respective chip and give each converter it's own trace to the VIN connector and I give it a 99.5% chance it will just work. If the input voltage will never exceed 16 V then you are allowed to make C6 a 16 V rated cap. But it is better to have some margin so use a 25 V or higher rated cap.

Comment: Why are C6 and C8 not identical? It won't be a problem if your input isn't more than 16V, but why not just use the same capacitor for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sheet is very clear: -

[image]

So you use one per instance of each LM2576 and make sure you have headroom voltage rating i.e. make C6 and C8 both 25 volt versions to be safe.